# Excel 2007 Recursion Multiplication Kaplan Meier Curve

Tags: excel, recursion

Consider the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgHoc.jpg

The columns are A, B, C and D.  The ratio column is column a divided by column b.  This will give you the decimals that are in parentheses of column C.  The last column is where the recursion takes place.  In the third row of column D there is 92%.  92% is the probability of all of the row C probabilities.  So c3*c4*c5=d5.  And the next probability for column D would be c3*c4*c5*c6, and so on.  How can I extrapolate this for the entire column if there are several hundred entries?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i'm not familiar with excel and i'm pretty sure that i can't type in c++ into a cell and have it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `=PRODUCT($C$3:C6)` so still get the calculation of the product for the terms, even when the list increases as C3 remain in place thank to the $ who lock the cell.

I hope this helps

Regards

Comment: thanks.  i ended up using a work-around for the recursion.  well, i suppose in essence it's still recursion but much less typing and margin for error